# ElasticSearch does not find by UTF8 characters

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm using ElasticSearch along with Symfony2 and FOSElasticaBundle. Then I try to find anything with ASCII characters only, it works like a charm.  Also, I'm using JSON array for data, and it converts unicode characters into something like \u00f8C. Could this affect my problem? My code for search:

```
function __construct(Request $request, TransformedFinder $artist_finder, TransformedFinder $picture_finder, Router $router)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->a_finder = $artist_finder;
    $this->p_finder = $picture_finder;
    $this->router = $router;
}

/**
 * @param $query
 * @return array
 */
public function search($query)
{
    $locale = $this->request->getLocale();

    $artist_results = $this->a_finder->find($query.'*', self::SEARCH_LIMIT);
    $gallery_results = $this->p_finder->find($query.'*', self::SEARCH_LIMIT);

    $results = array(
        'artist' => array(),
        'gallery' => array()
    );

    foreach($artist_results as $a)
    {
        $results['artist'][] = array(
            'url' => $this->router->generate('artist_page', ['slug' => $a->getSlug()]),
            'name' => $a->getInfo()[$locale]['name']. ' ' .$a->getInfo()[$locale]['surname']
        );
    }

    foreach($gallery_results as $a)
    {
        $results['gallery'][] = array(
            'url' => $this->router->generate('picture_page', ['slug' => $a->getSlug()]),
            'name' => $a->getInfo()[$locale]['title']
        );
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Also, does ES have ability to see no difference between lithuanian characters, for example "Š" and "S", "Ė" and "E" etc? I mean, I would like to get same results with query like "žąsis" and "zasis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to make it work. I had to use 2nd json_encode parameter JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for indexed values, witch I think makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the [analyser section of your fos_elastica bundle configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md#advanced-searching-example).

There are different analysers that can be applied depending on what you want. And there are specific ones for languages, check out the related [elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu plugin and some configuration for filters (in my case for czech language) ... e.g.

```
settings:
    analysis:
      analyzer:
        cs_collation:
          type: custom
          tokenizer: keyword
          filter: [trim,cs_icu_collation]
        cs_facets:
          type: custom
          tokenizer: keyword
          filter: [trim]
        custom_analyzer_cs:
          type     :    custom
          tokenizer:    nGram
          filter   :    [stopwords, lowercase, czech_stemmer, asciifolding, snowball, worddelimiter]


filter:
    czech_stemmer:
      type: stemmer
      name: czech
    cs_icu_collation:
      type: icu_collation
      stopwords: [_czech_]
      language: cs
```

Comment: Thank you, finally I've managed to make it work. I had to use 2nd json_encode parameter JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for indexed values, witch I think makes sense.